# Launcing google maps app from my app iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to launch Google maps app from my app. In the maps app I was to set the destination and the user decides to use his current location or enter address. Can any one guide me how to proceed with this. I absolute have no idea about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the current location you can use

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

To find the location you need to use google API as follows.

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)findTheLocation{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSArray *addressItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"Address URL : %@", locationString);
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    if ([addressItems count] >=4 && [[addressItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[addressItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[addressItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Address error.....");
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = latitude;
    coord.longitude = longitude;
    return coord;
}
```

Above function will return the coordinates of the address. You can display this coordination on map.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I am trying to launch the google maps app from my app and set the final destination. Can you tell me how to call the google maps app?

Comment: The following tutorial gives you the answer.
[link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/)

You can set your destination coordinate to `region.center`

Answer (score 3):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=INSERT_YOUR_QUERY_HERE"]]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how do we query in url?. I am sorry. I am absolutely clue less about google maps